# How can I make a div to disappear after couple of seconds?

Tags: jquery, dom, event-handling

I have the following function which fade out the div on touch but I want in the same time to make it disappear after 5 seconds in case the user will not react.
Any idea how shall I modify the code?

```
$('#ceva').on({
    'touchstart': function() {
        $('#ceva').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`delay`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) with `touchend` as follow.

> Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

```
$('#ceva').on({
    'touchstart': function() {
        $('#ceva').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

In `ready` add following:

```
$('#ceva').delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: I think you haven't understood my question. Your function is going to delay with 5 seconds after I touch. What I need is to disappear automatically after 5 second if I don't touch

Comment: This is calling only the first function

Comment: I want to disappear without any touching in 5 second otherwise it will disappear on touch instantly

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ceva").hide('blind', {}, 500)
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: and where shall I put the touchstart now?